# UI Tabs in Fancybox 2 with inline content. How to go directly to tab on click while preserving tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, fancybox-2

I have a fancybox with multiple instances of inline content. Once the fancybox is fired users can see different "views" with the help of ui tabs. However I am trying to directly link nav hrefs to these inline instances.

Currently if a user clicks any of the nav links the fancybox will open and they will always see the #sources "view".

I can link directly to other inline instances however I would only get that inline content and not the tabs themselves which are an important part of the design.

Its there a way I can launch the fancybox from the nav links preserve the ui-tabs and target the tab index (or id) itself? Is that even the solution?

**HTML**

the nav-primary and nav-secondary links are the nav links I was talking about as you can see they open up the fancybox by targeting #menu. #menu needs to be targeted for the ui-tabs-nav (tabs) to show.

```
<nav class="navigation">
<ul class="nav-primary">
  <li class="nav-primary-item"><a class="menu" href="#menu"><i class="ico plus-yellow">+</i> Sources</a></li>
  <li class="nav-primary-item"><a class="menu" href="#menu"><i class="ico plus-yellow">+</i> Topics</a></li>
  <li class="nav-primary-item"><a class="menu" href="#menu"><i class="ico plus-yellow">+</i> Geography</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav-secondary">
  <li class="nav-secondary-item"><a class="menu" href="#menu"><i class="ico plus-greyishblue">+</i> Tools</a></li>
  <li class="nav-secondary-item"><a class="menu" href="#menu"><i class="ico plus-greyishblue">+</i> Learn</a></li>
  <li class="nav-secondary-item"><a class="menu" href="#menu"><i class="ico plus-greyishblue">+</i> News</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="nav-menu" style="display: none">
  <div class="nav-tabs page_tabs" id="menu">
   <!---TABS I WANT TO PRESERVE--->
   <ul class="ui-tabs-nav" role="tablist">
    <li role="tab"><a href="#sources">Sources</a></li>
    <li role="tab"><a href="#topics">Topics</a></li>
    <li role="tab"><a href="#geography">Geography</a></li>
    <li role="tab"><a href="#tools">Tools</a></li>
    <li role="tab"><a href="#learn">Learn</a></li>
    <li role="tab"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
   </ul>

   <!--Sources and Uses-->
   <div id="sources">
     Content here
   </div>

   <!--Topics-->

   <div id="topics">
    Content Here
   </div>

   <!--Geography-->

   <div id="geography">
     Content Here
   </div>

   <!--Tools-->
   <div id="tools">
     Content Here
   </div>

   <!--Learn-->
   <div id="learn">
     Content Here
   </div>

   <!--News-->
   <div id="news">
     Content Here
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

**Fancybox JS**

```
$('.menu').fancybox({
  type: 'inline',
  scrolling: 'auto',
  width: 940,
  height: 'auto',
  padding: 0,
  autoSize: false,
  tpl: {
       closeBtn: '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close fancyboxBtn" href="javascript:;"></a>'
   },
  helpers: {
   overlay: {
       locked: false
   }
  }
 });
```

This should illustrate what I mean buy preserve the tabs. If one clicks this link

[image: with #menu as href]

They would get the sources content with the tab navigation

[image: fancybox with tab navigation always shows sources and uses first when href is #menu]

If one clicked this link with the href set directly to #sources content 
[image]

They would get this jacked up view of the fancybox with the tabs missing

[image]

Again how can I directly target the inline content from the navigation links without losing the tabs?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$(document).on("click", ".menu", function() {
var target = $(this).data("target");

if (target == 'sources') {
    jQuery('.page_tabs').tabs({ active: 0 });
}
if (target == 'topics') {
    jQuery('.page_tabs').tabs({ active: 1 });
}
if (target == 'geography') {
    jQuery('.page_tabs').tabs({ active: 2 });
}
if (target == 'tools') {
    jQuery('.page_tabs').tabs({ active: 3 });
}
if (target == 'learn') {
    jQuery('.page_tabs').tabs({ active: 4 });
}
if (target == 'news') {
    jQuery('.page_tabs').tabs({ active: 5 });
}
});
```